# Lame wav to array and back to wav with c/c++

Tags: c++, c, encoding, wav, lame

Can I convert a wav file to a simple c double or int array and convert back to a new wav file? I want to use some c filter in the wav file. I red that with lame it is possible. But I don't know how. Can someone link some documentation or code snippet, how I can use it?

wav file -> array -> some operation -> wav file

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: The [WAV format](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) is very simple - everything after the first 44 bytes is raw pcm data so trivial to copy into an array.  NumChannels (bytes offset 22) and BitsPerSample (offset 34) are probably the most interesting parts of the header to you.

Comment: @simonc: It's a common misconception that WAV files are very simple.  Data does **not** always appear at 44 bytes.  Other fields likewise can appear at different offsets.  The spec is a beast.  There are lots of optional chunks.  The data can appear in dozens of different formats.

Comment: It can, but if the output is produced by lame and if the stuff doesn't have to be of commercial quality; and taken the fact that this is apparently for a beginner, why to suggest something too complex and too "right" ?

Comment: @DietrichEpp Sounds like I've been reading the wrong doc, can you point me towards the spec please?  I'd also be interested if you know of any apps that output WAVs in other forms.

Comment: @simonc: I don't know where to get the spec.  You can also search for RIFF spec, if that helps.  Any program that puts more in the file than just sample data will add extra chunks.  For example, I just fired up "Amadeus Lite", recorded a short audio file, added a marker, and saved it.  The marker showed up as a "cue" chunk and the data chunk got pushed farther back in the file.  I can open up the file again and the marker is still there.  Actually, it's even possible to put the info chunk after the data chunk, as far as I know, which really screws things up.

Comment: I try to install with Macports and I try to compile from source but it's not working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659624/macports-2-1-2-git-and-libsndfile-installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Lame.  Lame is a tool for encoding MP3 files.

There are many libraries for reading and writing WAV files.  You can even write your own, but that's inconvenient because WAV files have so many different sample formats: 8-bit, 16-bit, 24-bit, floating point, ADPCM, µlaw, etc.

You can use [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) to read WAV files.

## Fields in WAV files do not have fixed offsets

The reason this is bold + large is because a lot of people think that the data in a WAV file always starts at 44 bytes.  This is simply not true.  A WAV file is a RIFF file, and can contain an arbitrary number of chunks of data, one *or more* of which contains sample data.  You'd be forgiven for being unable to handle esoteric WAV files, but if you make assumptions about the locations of data in the file you can end up with garbage.

Comment: thanks your quick answer, I try libsndfile.

Comment: Fields in Wav generated by Lame from same kind of source will have exactly the same kind of header.

Comment: can I use libsndfile in mac?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: What happens when the Lame developers decide to copy ID3 tags to the WAV file?  Sorry, I just don't see how assuming a fixed offset makes things easier, when using a library is already easy and doesn't involve making assumptions about other software.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: easy for who? Are you sure the library is available on the OP's system and it installs easily and all the dependencies are resolved? Anyway it's not a big step after having your valuable insights of the volatility of wav format to make some very easy tests to check that the 'data' or 'fmt' tags are where they are assumed -- and this is also a process, which any beginner programmer has to take to learn more valuable lessons.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: (1) Easy for the developer. (2) Yes, I am sure. You could have answered this yourself if you followed the link, "The library was written to compile and run on a Linux system but should compile and run on just about any Unix (including MacOS X). There are also pre-compiled binaries available for 32 and 64 bit windows."  (3) The asker came here to ask for help reading WAV files, not asking for a programming exercise to become better at writing libraries that parse WAV files.  Learning to use libraries is also a valuable experience. Learning to avoid NIH syndrome is also valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Wav format is quite well specified and it uses typically 2 channels of 16 bit samples. Those can be represented exactly both as integers, floats and doubles.

As told by *simonc* in the comment, the typical format is so simple, that it really doesn't pay to learn using a library. If the length of the wav doesn't change, the conversion / filtering can be done simply by:

```
fread(header,1,44,in_file); fwrite(header,1,44,out_file);
short int block[1024];  // left and right channel will be interleaved.
while (c=fread(block, 2, 1024, fp))
{  
    filter_in_place(block,c); 
    fwrite(block, 2,c, out_file);
}
```