# MacPorts 2.1.2 git and libsndfile installation

Tags: xcode, git, macports, libsndfile

I try to install git and libsndfile with port, but I get this messages.

```
MacPorts 2.1.2
Error: Port git not found
Error: Port libsndfile not found
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `port search git` to **search** for the right port.

This article will show you how to install the Version Control *Git* :
[Installing git with MacPorts](http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/installing-git-with-macports-197.html)

Do a `sudo port selfupdate` to *updating the MacPorts base sources*

then do a `sudo port install libsndfile`.

You may want to perform a `sudo port upgrade outdated` to upgrade your installed ports first.